# How to run Indicator-Synapse in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu 13.10 and I have added the following repositories to install Indicator-Synapse

ppa:elementary-os/daily
ppa:elementary-os/unstable-upstream

And successfully installed Indicator-Synapse using apt-get. However, I am unable to find or even run Indicator-Synapse from the command line and cannot find it to add to the panel in Lubuntu. I've successfully installed Synapse but not the Indicator-Synapse.

Can anybody assist?

Comment: Are you able to use synapse? You should not need the 'synapse indicator'.

Comment: Ah sorry if I did not explain this too clearly. Indicator-Synapse is very similar to Synapse but a different program. Just wanted to mention that I had already installed Synapse in case someone suggested as an alternative.

Comment: The correct question would be then how to run Ubuntu Indicators in the lxde desktop, since indicator are a direfent aproach of notification icons. No idea if this is doable.

Comment: `sudo apt install synapse`